# Why is audio not playing on Colab when on different tab?

Tags: audio, python, jupyter-notebook

I have homework to do. I also have to train a deep learning model on Colab for different configurations. Training with each configuration needs around 30 minutes and I need to switch to a different tab to do homework in the meantime. So, I wanted audio notification once the training cells completed running. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54293537/9278978) gave me the **what to add** after the required code **to play a sound**.

It works. But the only problem is **it doesn't work if I'm on a different tab or have kept the tab containing Colab in background**. It waits for me to go to the tab and as soon as I go to that tab, it plays the sound. This is unfortunate on my part because this means I'm back to square one.

Now, in the second answer to the above linked question someone has mentioned that it didn't work when the tab was minimized but it did work when the Colab tab was in the background. But for me that doesn't work too.

*What I have tried*:

1. There is a function that plays the audio. It takes input either a path or a web link. I have tried links, kept the audio in drive, mounted it and added its path, kept the audio in colab  storage itself, added its path. I thought it might be a problem with the location of the music file. But it was playing when in the tab. It was not playing the audio when I was on a different tab or kept the Colab tab in background.
2. I have checked permissions for that tab, I have allowed Sound, Flash, Notifications, Pop-ups and refreshed the tab to let the changes take place.

So, now I'm confused as to where the problem lies and how to solve it? How to let the sound play even if I'm on a different tab?

*A note:* Even the new "desktop notifications for cell completion" setting that can be found in Colab doesn't produce notifications for me. *Other sites such as Youtube play audio even if I am on different tab.*

*Additional Info:*

Browser: Google Chrome, Version 86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Sound Card/Driver: Intel (R) Display Audio, Realtek High Definition Audio

Windows: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching I found that there is something called **Autoplay policy** for browsers that has been imposed by developers to prevent unwanted audio and video from playing.

Best way to check if you have audio autoplay in tab B from tab A (that means you opened the audio based tab B from tab A and did not switch to B and checked if you could hear audio) is by opening [this audio link](https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20180430/complete--_us_1.mp3) in a new tab from your current tab (which is probably this). If audio plays without going to that tab, then my autoplay requirement in the question is satisfied and the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54293537/9278978) work when on another tab.

So, my only success was with FireFox browser:

*Firefox:* Version-82.0.3 (64-bit)

1. The "*Allow audio and video*" autoplay setting doesn't work for me.
2. Type *about:config* in a new tab
3. Toggle *media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground* to false

*Chrome:* Version-86.0.4240.193 (Official Build) (64-bit)

1. *chrome://flags/* does not contain the autoplay-policy flag anymore
2. *chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required* from command line does not allow autoplaying audio too.

*Edge:* Version-86.0.622.63 (Official build) (64-bit)

1. Same issue as chrome, the *Media autoplay* setting does not work for above case.
2. There is no flag related to autoplaying audio in *edge://flags*